# Delete notification after clicking on 'Delete'

Tags: java, android, firebase, notifications

I have a notification in my app with the following code:

```
@SuppressLint("RestrictedApi")
    void ShowNotification(String title, String text, int color) {

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            channelId = getString(R.string.default_notification_channel_id);
            String description = getString(R.string.channel_description);
            NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel(channelId, "MyNew notification", NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT);
            channel.setDescription(description);
            // Register the channel with the system; you can't change the importance or other notification behaviors after this
            NotificationManager notificationManager = getSystemService(NotificationManager.class);
            notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel);
        }
        Intent deleteIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        deleteIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_DELETE);
        deleteIntent.putExtra(EXTRA_NOTIFICATION_ID, 0);
        PendingIntent deletePendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(this, 0, deleteIntent, 0);

        // Create pending intent, mention the Activity which needs to be
        //triggered when user clicks on notification
        PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,
                new Intent(this, MainActivity.class), PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);


        NotificationCompat.Builder mNotify = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, channelId);
        mNotify.setLights(color, 100 , 200);
        mNotify.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_action_name);
        mNotify.setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory. decodeResource (getResources() , R.drawable.ic_action_name)) ;
        mNotify.setContentTitle(title);
        mNotify.setOngoing(true);

        mNotify.setShowWhen(true);
        mNotify.setContentText(text);
        mNotify.setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText("Much longer text that cannot fit one line..."));
        mNotify.setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND);

        mNotify.addAction(R.mipmap.shield3_foreground, "Delete", deletePendingIntent);
        mNotify.setContentIntent(contentIntent);//Activity which needs to be triggered when user clicks on notification
        NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        int mId = 1001;
        try {
            mNotificationManager.notify(mId, mNotify.build());

        }
        catch (Exception e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
    }
```

My notifications works fine, but the problem is that, when I click on 'Delete' in Notification, it does not remove notification.

I understand, that I have to use cancel() in my code, but have no idea how to use it here and where to use this method. What should I do, in order to use 'Delete' on my notification? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Use `BroadCastReceiver`

1. `deleteIntent` set by `BroadCastReceiver.class`
2. `deletePendingIntent` set by `PendingIntent.getBroadCast()`
3. `cancel(id)` or `cancelAll()` in `BroadCastReceiver`

more detail :
[android codelabs](https://developer.android.com/codelabs/advanced-android-kotlin-training-notifications#4) help you.

#### update

In your code, your `deleteIntent` is for  `MainActivity` and `deletePendingIntent` is from `Service`, It's not matched.

If you don't want `Service` or `BroadcastReceiver` and just want to use `MainActivity`, Change code like below

```java
Intent deleteIntent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
deleteIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_DELETE);
//getService() -> getActivity()
PendingIntent deletePendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, deleteIntent, 0);
```

and you need to handle that action

```java
//onCreate() in MainActivity
String action = getIntent().getAction();
if (action != null && action.equals(Intent.ACTION_DELETE)) {
    notificationUtil.deleteNotification(this);
    //if you don't want open app
    finish();
}

//...

//in NotificationUtil
void deleteNotification(Context context) {
    NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    mNotificationManager.cancel(mId);
}
```

#### *It's bad idea*

- using `BroadCastReceiver` better
- read [android codelabs (java)](https://developer.android.com/codelabs/android-training-notifications?index=..%2F..%2Fandroid-training&hl=pt#4) for more detail

Comment: Thanks for reply, but I don't need to delete notification from somewhere. I just want to remove it from screen with 'Delete' (not a swipe). Thanks for Kotlin example, but It doesn't help me. Can you share the Java code, please. Appreciate.

Comment: I update answer. And read `BroadcastReceiver` document. It is fit in your situation.(if you don't want to show `Activity`)

Comment: Many thanks! it works. I removed notificationUtil in notificationUtil.deleteNotification(this) and now its perfect.